# Why are min-content and max-content invalid values for the minmax function? MDN says otherwise

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm reading MDN articles on [minmax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) and [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat). Both say I can pass `min-content` and `max-content` into `minmax`, but when I attempt to do this, the Firefox inspector tells me it's an invalid property value.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  background: gray;
}

.cell {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
</div>
```

If you open the inspector, you'll see it's invalid (tested on FF and Chrome):

[image]

If you change it to `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));`, the grid works as expected.

These articles have similar examples using `min-content` and `max-content`, and they also directly state you can use it as a keyword, so why is Firefox reporting this as invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer was in the [repeat article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat), but it only applies because I'm using `auto-fit`:

> If you use `auto-fill` or `auto-fit` to set the repeat count, you may only specify track sizes using the `<fixed-size>` type, not the `<track-size>` type.
>
> ...
>
> [image]

You can use `min-content` and `max-content` in `minmax`, but only if the other value is a length or percentage.

I have modified my original example to show the correct usage:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 40%));
  gap: 10px;
  background: gray;
}

.cell {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
</div>
```